# Underline a number in an siunitx table (in beamer)

Tags: tables, beamer, siunitx, underline

I want a table column to be aligned using the thousands comma. But when I try to underline the number it moves and the comma disappears.

MWE:

```
[![\documentclass\[t,xcolor=table\]{beamer}
\usepackage\[group-separator={,}\]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}\[\]
        \begin{tabular}{SS}
            12000             & 1.4 \\
            \underline{13000} & 1.2 \\
            14000 & 1.2 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Underlining has to be applied *after* the alignment functions of `siunitx` have worked. the best way is to put the number into a `\tablenum` argument. We need a little bit of work to help `siunitx` here:

```
\documentclass[t,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage[group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=5.0]S[table-format = 1.1]}
            12000             & 1.4 \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{\underline{\tablenum[table-format=5.0]{13000}}}
              & 1.2 \\
            14000 & 1.2 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've set the column widths to the right size for their content: that's not vital but does make things look a lot better.

Comment: Would it be possible to produce the same with double underline, and double dashed underline?

Comment: @MorZahavi Anything that can be used to 'box up' the content will work here